# Loop through variable on print

Tags: python

**code**

```
print(coins_in_the_bag) #{'Bug Out Bag': ['q', 0.25, 100], 'sm': ['q', 0.25, 10]}
    print('\n')
    print('for bag: {}\n total:{} '.format(
            my_bag, 
            for b in my_bag:
                total = float(coins_in_the_bag[b][1])*float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][2]))
            total
    )
```

How can I do my loop in the `second parameter` in my print statement?

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
Bug Out Bag:
Total: 25

sm:
2.5
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
    for b in my_bag:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you

Comment: A `for` loop is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up the answer you wrote

```
my_coin = coins_in_the_bag[my_bag]
original_total = float(my_coin[1])*float(my_coin[2])
print('for bag: {}\n original{}\n new total:{}\n '.format(
    my_bag, 
    original_total,
    original_total - float(amount_to_move)
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `for` loop, it has to come before the `print` as its own statement; you can't use arbitrary code as an expression.

```
total = 0
for b in my_bag:
    total += float(coins_in_the_bag[b[1]])*float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][2]))
    print('for bag: {}\n total:{} '.format(my_bag, total))
```

However, you *can* write a single expression that computes the sum without using a `for` loop. For example,

```
print('for bag: {}\n total:{} '.format(
        my_bag,
        sum(float(coins_in_the_bag[b[1]])*float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][2])) for b in my_bag)
)
```

Comment: The first code block should just use `=` for total if I'm reading the example output correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, I hope that this will help someone!

```
print('for bag: {}\n original{}\n new total:{}\n '.format(
    my_bag, 
    float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][1])*float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][2]),
    float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][1])*float(coins_in_the_bag[my_bag][2]) - float(amount_to_move)
    )
)
```

Comment: You could store the value of the multiplication before the print to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Please write an answer displaying this.